# \parencite prints out almost all authors in one case and only one in another

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-citations

I have two similar references:

```
@article{mercury4,
  author = {Macrae, C. F. and Sovago, I. and Cottrell, S. J. and Galek, P. T. A. and McCabe, P. and Pidcock, E. and Platings, M. and Shields, G. P. and Stevens, J. S. and Towler, M. and Wood, P. A.},
  title = {Mercury 4.0: from visualization to analysis, design and prediction},
  journal = {Journal of Applied Crystallography},
  volume = {53},
  pages = {226-235},
  year = {2020},
  doi = {10.1107/S1600576719014092}
}
```

and

```
@article{creatineCSD,
  author = {Arlin, J.-B. and Bhardwaj, R. M. and Johnston, A. and Miller, G. J. and Bardin, J. and MacDougall, F. and Fernandes, P. and Shankland, K. and David, W. I. F. and Florence, A. J.},
  title = {Structure and stability of two polymorphs of creatine and its monohydrate},
  journal = {CrystEngComm},
  volume = {16},
  pages = {8197},
  year = {2014},
  doi = {10.1039/C4CE00508B}
}
```

and i use them in the same place:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/JOHJIB01_Hb1.png}
    \caption{Creatine crystal structure \parencite{creatineCSD} in Mercury \parencite{mercury4}}
\end{figure}
```

but the result is this:

[image]

and i want this:

[image]

how can this be done?
this is biblatex with apa style

Comment: APA style requires that more names be shown for different lists that would otherwise abbreviate to the same "et al."-ed short form. See https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/same-year-first-author. If I just include the two entries you have shown so far and cite them I get "Arlin et al., 2014; Macrae et al., 2020" (https://gist.github.com/moewew/cd6f69e65db712c41b56e0693f285c93). This suggest that there is another entry (or other context) that makes a difference here.